# how to update navbar links after login in vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am creating an auth system using Laravel and Vue.js, and I have stored an api token in localStorage. But when the user logs into the application, the header links remain 'Login' and 'Signup'. I want to update these links after login. My code is

```
<b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto" v-if="this.$store.state.user === null">
    <li class="nav-item"><router-link class="nav-link text-white" to="/signin">SignIn</router-link></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><router-link class="nav-link" to="/signup">SignUp</router-link></li>
</b-navbar-nav>
<b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto" v-else>
    <b-button class="btn-sm btn-success" v-on:click="getBucket()">Create Bucket</b-button>
    <b-button class="btn-sm btn-info ml-1" v-on:click="logout()">Logout</b-button>
</b-navbar-nav>
```

and my store index file is as

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
      user: localStorage.getItem('userToken')
   },
   mutations: {
   },
   actions: {
   },
   modules: {
   }
 })
```

Comment: What that means is no item is being retrieved from `localStorage`

Comment: i need to reload the page to update changes, i don't want to reload the page.

Comment: Maybe you could use a getter, instead of accessing state directly?

Comment: If the `userToken` isn't available when the app loads, then as long as you set it when the user logs in, you wouldn't need any reload.

Comment: @Dan but when user submit form and userToken is in localstorage then navbar not updated, what should i do?

Comment: You have to set the token in `state.user` at that time as well, since the template checks that.  Once `state.user` is set, the template will react.  I posted an answer demonstrating.

Comment: Store the userToken in vuex state and use a getter to check for it.

Comment: How did this work out for you?  Did you try the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Vuex action for login, you could use something like this:

```js
actions: {
  async login({ commit }, credentials) {
    const response = await axios.post(...); // use `credentials` to log in
    const token = response.data;
    commit('SET_TOKEN', token);
  }
},
mutations: {
  SET_TOKEN(state, token) {
    localStorage.setItem('userToken', token);  // <-- set the token in storage
    state.user = token; // <-- also set the token in state
  }
}
```

At the time you login, you set the token in storage, and also set the token to `state.user`.